# InputStream.read() hangs on reading a file

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream, fileinputstream

In my app, i'm sending a file from a client, using sockets. On the other side, another client receive the file using InputStream and then bufferedOutputStream save the file in the system.

I don´t know why, the file isn´t utterly transmited. I think this is because of network overload, anyway, i don´t know how to solve it.

Transmiter is:

```
Log.d(TAG,"Reading...");
                bufferedInputStream.read(byteArrayFile, 0, byteArrayFile.length);
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending...");
                bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArrayFile,0,byteArrayFile.length);

bufferedOutputStream.flush();
```

Receiver is:

```
 bufferedOutputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                            byteArray=new byte[fileSize];

                            int currentOffset = 0;

                            bytesReaded = bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
                            currentOffset=bytesReaded;

                            do {
                                bytesReaded = bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray, currentOffset, (byteArray.length-currentOffset));
                                if(bytesReaded >= 0){ currentOffset += bytesLeidos;
                               }
                            } while(bytesReaded > -1 && currentOffset!=fileSize);


                            bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArray,0,currentOffset);
```

Comment: try to log the value of bytesReaded and see how is it going

Comment: Typically, stepping through with your debugger and inspecting variable values is recommended.

Comment: I have done it before. For example, if the file have 10000 bytes, it gets stuck when it have received 9000 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't state where `filesize` came from, but there are numerous problems with this code. Too many to mention. Throw it all away and use `DataInputStream.readFully()`. Or use the following copy loop, which doesn't require a buffer the size of the file, a technique which does not scale, assumes that the file size fits into an `int`, and adds latency:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this at both ends. If you're sending multiple files via the same connection it gets more complex, but you haven't stated that.

Comment: In your loop, "in" variable would be a "InputStream"?

Comment: @MMManuel Of course, and `out` would be an `OutputStream`. I didn't think this needed stating.

Comment: Shouldn´t offset be incremented in "count" every write event?

Comment: @MMManuel No. It's the offset into the buffer, not into the target stream.